# How to retrive geolocation information from JPEG EXIF data?

Tags: php, geolocation, gd, exif

I was working on image manipulation with php gd library. Just now God appeared and told me that we can retrieve exif data from jpeg, tiff images.But, he did not tell me how!

I tried surfing about it and found some posts about retrieving the data. All was good here on earth until I tried getting geo-location data. I couldn't find any solution to get that data.

Comment: [exif_read_data](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php)

Comment: My God is displeased with posts that don't feature any research, and He told me to downvote your question. Praise be!

Comment: Ha ha.. 
I researched about the [exif_read_data] (http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php) and I am able to retrive orientation, thumbnail, camera parameters from it but was helpless about the geo-location data. I couldn't get much info about the exif geo-location retrieval thus couldn't produce any research.
Now, INDIA and UK both are democratic republics, you can downvote if you want to.
Thanks again for you time..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I mentioned in the comments [exif_read_data](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php). Now that I'm at my desk I can elaborate a bit more. I created a function a while back to do exactly this:

```
// get geo-data from image
function get_image_location($file) {
    if (is_file($file)) {
        $info = exif_read_data($file);
        if ($info !== false) {
            $direction = array('N', 'S', 'E', 'W');
            if (isset($info['GPSLatitude'], $info['GPSLongitude'], $info['GPSLatitudeRef'], $info['GPSLongitudeRef']) &&
                in_array($info['GPSLatitudeRef'], $direction) && in_array($info['GPSLongitudeRef'], $direction)) {

                $lat_degrees_a = explode('/',$info['GPSLatitude'][0]);
                $lat_minutes_a = explode('/',$info['GPSLatitude'][1]);
                $lat_seconds_a = explode('/',$info['GPSLatitude'][2]);
                $lng_degrees_a = explode('/',$info['GPSLongitude'][0]);
                $lng_minutes_a = explode('/',$info['GPSLongitude'][1]);
                $lng_seconds_a = explode('/',$info['GPSLongitude'][2]);

                $lat_degrees = $lat_degrees_a[0] / $lat_degrees_a[1];
                $lat_minutes = $lat_minutes_a[0] / $lat_minutes_a[1];
                $lat_seconds = $lat_seconds_a[0] / $lat_seconds_a[1];
                $lng_degrees = $lng_degrees_a[0] / $lng_degrees_a[1];
                $lng_minutes = $lng_minutes_a[0] / $lng_minutes_a[1];
                $lng_seconds = $lng_seconds_a[0] / $lng_seconds_a[1];

                $lat = (float) $lat_degrees + ((($lat_minutes * 60) + ($lat_seconds)) / 3600);
                $lng = (float) $lng_degrees + ((($lng_minutes * 60) + ($lng_seconds)) / 3600);
                $lat = number_format($lat, 7);
                $lng = number_format($lng, 7);

                //If the latitude is South, make it negative. 
                //If the longitude is west, make it negative
                $lat = $info['GPSLatitudeRef'] == 'S' ? $lat * -1 : $lat;
                $lng = $info['GPSLongitudeRef'] == 'W' ? $lng * -1 : $lng;

                return array(
                    'lat' => $lat,
                    'lng' => $lng
                );
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

This function is intended to work with file uploads, for example:

```
if (($geo = get_image_location($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) && !empty($geo)) {
    // upload file
} else {
    // file does not appear to contain any location information
}
```

That should give you a good start.

Comment: Thanks mister martin, your code worked for me.. It exactly gives what I was looking for..
Thanks again from INDIA..
_/\\_